# I found No way to build facebook integration with my website

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I tried in many ways.. i used php-sdk and in many other ways... but i am not able to connect my website with facebook... actually.. i am doing my project in codeigniter. Can anybody plz suggest me to connect to facebook login and share using codeigniter.

```
<?php
            include "libs/facebook.php";
            $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => '376406812408828',
                'sec`enter code here`ret' => 'ca1eb65bde82a4009c31b4a5adb047b5',
                'cookie' => true
            ));
            print_r($facebook);
            $session = $facebook->getUser();
            echo $session;
            $me=null;
            if($session)
            {
                try
                {

                    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
                    echo $me;
                     $facebook->api('/me/feed','post',array('message' => 'Hello World!'));
                }
                catch(FacebookApiException $e)
                {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
            if($me)
            {
                $logoutUrl = $facebook ->getLogoutUrl();
                echo "<a href=".$logoutUrl.">Logout</a>";
            }
            else
            {

                $loginUrl = $facebook ->getLoginUrl(array(        
                    'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,read_friendlists'
                ));
                echo "<a href=".$loginUrl.">Login</a>";
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Nothing is Impossible Dude!!!

Answer (score 2):

**Danny Tran has provided [A Simple & Easy Facebook Library for CodeIgniter](https://github.com/dannybtran/CI_Facebook).**

> **CI_Facebook** is a `Facebook Library for CodeIgniter`.
>
> Simply copy/merge all the files into the corresponding locations and
>   setup config/facebook.php.
>
> There are unit tests written for each function/class.  You will need
>   PHPUnit to execute them.
>
> Accessing the Facebook object is easy since the hook is auto-loading
>   it.
>
> ```
> e.g. $user_data = $this->facebook->fb->api_client->fql_query("select name from user where uid = TARGETUSERID");
> ```

Link to library on **Github**: **https://github.com/dannybtran/CI_Facebook**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of weeks I had to do the same, and after and I came up with this. I needed it for an ajax login, but it mostly suits everyone needs.

This is the first step, it prompts the facebook login (if you are not already logged) and then redirect to your previously set uri.

```
$this->load->library('facebook_handler');
$this->facebook_handler->loginBegin($this->config->item('endpointfacebook'));
```

**Facebook_handler in libraries folder**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 


class Facebook_handler extends ML_index
{

        var $scope = "email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_website,read_stream, publish_stream, read_friendlists";


    function __construct()
    {   parent::__construct();

        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->config->load('mlogin_config'); //Config where I have the keys

        if ( ! $this->CI->config->item('facebook_api_key') || ! $this->CI->config->item('facebook_api_key_secret') )
        {
            throw new Exception( "Your application id and secret are required in order to connect to {$this->providerId}.", 4 );
        }
        include_once(APPPATH.'libraries/Facebook/base_facebook.php'); //Place where I've situated the facebook libraries
        include_once(APPPATH.'libraries/Facebook/facebook.php');

        $this->fb = new Facebook( ARRAY( 'appId' => $this->CI->config->item('facebook_api_key'),'cookie'=>true, 'secret' => $this->CI->config->item('facebook_api_key_secret') ) ); 
        $this->user = $this->fb->getUser();

    } 
     /*The login process starts here, endpoint is the redirect_url for facebook*/
    function loginBegin($endpoint) 
    {
        $scope=$this->CI->config->item('facebook_scope');
        if( isset( $scope ) && ! empty( $scope ) )
        {
            $this->scope = $scope;
        }
        $this->logout();
        $url = $this->fb->getLoginUrl( array( 'domain'=>base_url(),'scope' => $this->scope, 'redirect_uri' => $endpoint,'display' => 'popup' ) );

        redirect($url); 
    }

    /*Function to get user data*/
    function getUser(){
        if ($this->user) {
          try {
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $user_profile = $this->fb->api('/me');
            return $user_profile;
          } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            return false;
            }
        }else{
            $this->output->set_output('no logueado');
        }
    }

    /*Facebook logout, it destroys facebook sessions. I dont really use this*/
    function logout(){
        $this->fb->destroySession();
    }   
}

?>
```

**The function to redirect to**

```
function closewindowfacebook(){
           $this->load->library('facebook_handler');
           $userprofile=$this->facebook_handler->getUser();


            if ($userprofile!=false){
               $fb_uid = $this->facebook_handler->fb->getUser();
               $fb_email=$userprofile['email'];
               $fb_name=$userprofile['name'];

                /*My function to connect to the website, that you'd do it yourself*/
               //$this->auth->try_fb_login($fb_uid,$fb_email,$fb_name);

                 /*I use this to close the popup window*/
                             die('<script type="text/javascript">
                    window.opener.everythingready();
                    window.close();
                </script>');

            }  else{
                echo 'error ';
            }


    }
```

Ask if you have any further question